# Can we Create ListCtrl in view in MDI application or we always need to draw it?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mfc, mdi

i am currently trying to create a listctrl in view part of my MDI aaplication,as i am linking a listctrl pointer so,i need to draw it once on view but,i m not able to do it,as i am a beginner,can anyone suggest me the answer

```
    int CDB_DOC_VIEW_MYView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;
    CDB_DOC_VIEW_MYDoc *pDoc = GetDocument();
    CRect WndRect, ListRect;
    this->GetWindowRect(&WndRect);
    //CListCtrl *pListCtrl = new CListCtrl();
    CListCtrl &pListCtrl = GetListCtrl();
    /*ListRect.top    = WndRect.top - 5;
    ListRect.left   = WndRect.left - 5;
    ListRect.bottom = WndRect.bottom - 5;
    ListRect.right  = WndRect.right - 5;*/
    pListCtrl.Create( WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | LVS_REPORT , ListRect, this, ID_LIST_CTRL); 
    for( int col = 0; col < 5; col++ )
    {
        pListCtrl.InsertColumn(col, _T("1")); 
    } 
    pListCtrl.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    return 0;
}
```

that's what i did ?

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't think your question makes any sense.

Comment: @JonathanPotter its not just you. I *think* the OP is trying to use a ListView *as* an MDI child window; not as a child control full-encompassing an MDI child client area as most people would code it. Could be wrong. Tis indeed hard to tell.

Comment: i,just ,little modified the code,nw,it works,,,,but ,it displays listctrl only after placing this code in onsize() function,,       void CDB_DOC_VIEW_MYView::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CListView::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    if(::IsWindow(m_listCtrl.m_hWnd))
        m_listCtrl.MoveWindow(0,0,cx,cy,TRUE);

}but i am ,notaware,why this stament is required as i got getwindowrect() of view,and which i ,placed in the create function()

Comment: GetWindowRect returns screen coordinates. That needs to be convert to client coordinates to create something within the window. You can use ScreenToClient to do that.

Comment: ScreenToClient(&WndRect); not working,still need to write MoveWindow(),,i just want to know without MoveWindow() where it has gone ,if created ,then,,,,why not displaying?

Answer (score 0):

Try to derive your CView from [CListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3ch0w2y.aspx).

Comment: i have,achieved this,task,thanks to all of u,,for your suggestions